# jQuery validation of multiple not equal inputs

Tags: jquery, validation, email, input

I've managed to set up jQuery validate plugin on my form and I gave rules for two fields in which their values should not match. Specifically, the email and email_2 inputs can not be the same now, and that works. But my real need is to validate multiple inputs in the same way (in this case 4 of them). I have email, email_2, email_3, email_4 and none of them should not be equal. You can see it in my [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zPetY/), and if you have solution, you can update it and put it back in answer:

html:

```
<form id="signupform" method="post">
<input id="email" name="username" />
<br/ >
<input id="email_2" name="email_2" />
<br />
<input id="email_3" name="email_3" />
<br />
<input id="email_4" name="email_4" />
<br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />   
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$.validator.addMethod("notequal", function(value, element) {
 return $('#email').val() != $('#email_2').val()}, 
 "* You've entered this one already");

// validate form    
$("#signupform").validate({

rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        notequal: true
    },
    email_2: {
        required: true,
        notequal: true
    },
},
});
```

what is the best solution for validate of all inputs?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.anujgakhar.com/2010/05/24/jquery-validator-plugin-and-notequalto-rule-with-multiple-fields/

Comment: Thank you, but, I tried to do like this and I get error on jQuery library, it seems that this doesn't work on latest 1.10.1...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it still works with 1.10.1

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/j952T/)

source: http://www.anujgakhar.com/2010/05/24/jquery-validator-plugin-and-notequalto-rule-with-multiple-fields/

HTML

```
<form id="signupform" method="post">
    <p>
        <input class="distinctemails" id="email" name="username" /></p>
    <p>
        <input class="distinctemails" id="email_2" name="email_2" /></p>
    <p>
        <input class="distinctemails" id="email_3" name="email_3" /></p>
    <p>
        <input class="distinctemails" id="email_4" name="email_4" /></p>
    <p>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqualToGroup", function (value, element, options) {
    // get all the elements passed here with the same class
    var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(options[0]);
    // the value of the current element
    var valueToCompare = value;
    // count
    var matchesFound = 0;
    // loop each element and compare its value with the current value
    // and increase the count every time we find one
    jQuery.each(elems, function () {
        thisVal = $(this).val();
        if (thisVal == valueToCompare) {
            matchesFound++;
        }
    });
    // count should be either 0 or 1 max
    if (this.optional(element) || matchesFound <= 1) {
        //elems.removeClass('error');
        return true;
    } else {
        //elems.addClass('error');
    }
}, jQuery.format("Please enter a Unique Value."))

// validate form    
$("#signupform").validate({

    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        },
        email_2: {
            required: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        },
        email_3: {
            required: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        },
        email_4: {
            required: true,
            notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctemails']
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: thank you, works like charm! I guess I've missed an error somewhere else. I though that it's not supported when console gave me library error

Comment: what if i have array of email like email[] not email_1 , email_2 ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.unique():

```
uniqArray = $.unique(emailsArray);
if (uniqArray.length != emailsArray.length) {
    <your magic here>
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear how to do it, at last, I'm jquery nooby. could you show me in my jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/zPetY/ please?

Comment: kei's solution is much better, actually. I did not knew that "validator" had such feature

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqArray = emailsArray.slice();

$.unique(uniqArray);

if (uniqArray.length != emailsArray.length) {
    <your magic here>
}
```