# jQuery validator notEqual to multiple values

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a text input called **strCompanyName** which I need to perform some validation on. 
Now I have the below working fine where I get a warning if the text in the input matches "*Company*", however, I am unsure how I would check to see if the input matches a number of values ie. "Company", "Your Company", "Your Company Name"

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
 return this.optional(element) || value.toLowerCase() != param.toLowerCase();
}, "Please specify your company name");


$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    strCompanyName: { notEqual: "Company" }
  }
});
```

Any help would be greatful.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964288/jquery-validation-of-multiple-not-equal-inputs

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks Jonathan, however that is checking multiple inputs, where I need to check all values against one input.

Comment: Oh, I see. Another approach below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your custom validator to split on a symbol (say, pipe) and validate against the subsequent array:

http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/40/

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || param.toLowerCase().split('|').indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) < 0;
}, "Please specify your company name");
```

and

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    strCompanyName: { notEqual: "Company|Another Company|Etc" }
  }
});
```